# Is it possible to keep a socket alive even after closing the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, voip

I have a voip app, and a customer would like to still be available after closing the app. Can I do something to make my app work like facetime?

The app has to login on our signaling server. The server relays messages like "start a call" to the clients.
So if A wants to call B, A has to open a socket and send the login signal (same for B) and then send a "call_create" signal to the server with a parameter "user" set to "B". The server then looks at the message, sees that it is meant for B and sends it to B (if B is logged in as well). B now receives the message that A wants to start a call and can send an "accept" back to the server. The server sends this message back to A and the call gets started.

Now, when the app is closed (double tap home button, swipe up), obviously the socket is killed as well. But one of our customers wants to still receive calls after killing the app (long story, but there is no other way).
I know facetime does not have to run to be able to receive calls, but I'm not sure if this is possible with a regular app (facetime is part of the OS). Ideally I would move the logging in part to the settings menu, just like facetime, and then have a connection with the signaling server all the time, regardless of the app running or not.

Comment: This looks like a design problem. You might like to consider splitting your app into two. One part running in the background keeping alive the connection to the signalling server and spawing the thr other part, the frontend if necessary. As you cannot expect your phone to receive calls if it's switched off ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need utilize [push notification feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html). In case your product supports also android see Google Cloud Messages.

Comment: I'm aware of push notifications, my problem is that the user has to be logged in on the signaling server. If this is the only way, a lot of work will have to be done to switch to a system that utilizes push notifications.

Comment: to make push notification working, you don't have to be loged-in. It is enough if you log in once (you need pass to the server id of device and pair this id with user login name).

Comment: Yes but my signaling server requires a login

Comment: Can you modify server code (or can you make some one to add features to server)? If not than this is hard to solve. If you can than server detects if socket is open if not then he sends push notification to Apple (Apple forwards this to device).

Comment: That's the plan right now, but it will take some time and we have a deadline coming up. Anyway, thanks for your help.